# How to fix the error " 'attribute' appears more than one time in Route template" on .NET Core framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routes

I'm developing an API controller, but for some reason, the server throws this error:

> System.ArgumentException: The route parameter name 'SubjectId' appears more than one time in the route template. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')

This is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Contracts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Services.Abstractions;

namespace Presentation.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class SubjectController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceManager _serviceManager;

        public SubjectController(IServiceManager serviceManager) => _serviceManager = serviceManager;

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSubjects(Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var accountsDto = await _serviceManager.SubjectService.GetByIdAsync(id, cancellationToken);

            return Ok(accountsDto);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id:guid}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSubjectById(Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var accountDto = await _serviceManager.SubjectService.GetByIdAsync(id,  cancellationToken);

            return Ok(accountDto);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAccount(Guid id,  SubjectForCreationDto subjectForCreationDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var subject = await _serviceManager.SubjectService.CreateAsync(subjectForCreationDto, id, cancellationToken);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetSubjectById), new { ownerId = subject.SubjectId}, subject);
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id:guid}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAccount(Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _serviceManager.SubjectService.DeleteAsync(id, cancellationToken);

            return NoContent();
        }
        
        [HttpPut("{id:guid}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSubject(Guid id, SubjectForUpdateDto subjectForUpdate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _serviceManager.SubjectService.UpdateAsync(id, subjectForUpdate, cancellationToken);

            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the endpoint configuration, and everything was fine. I think I need some help because I'm not familiar with this framework.

This is the endpoint config in `Startup.cs`:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
```

And this is my `Program.cs`

```
public class Program
{
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var webHost = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            await webHost.RunAsync();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

Could anyone point me to what is wrong with this code?

Comment: could you post program.cs/startup.cs  "app.xxx" related codes?

Comment: Seems not the right controller. The error is about the actions with parameter "SubjectId"